# Wrong output for a program rotating an array by d elements

Tags: arrays

This code is for rotating an array by d elements e.g. for d=3 input array={1,2,3,4,5,6,} output={4,5,6,1,2,3} . Now I tried to run this code on two different platforms.

1. Online gdb compiler and it was not printing any output
2. In VS Code it is displaying proper out with this code but if I comment the code for printing the array in `rotate_array_by_d()` then it is not displaying any output either.

What is the reason for this?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void rotate_arary_by_d(int a[],int n,int d)
{
    int *p;
    for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
    {
        p[j]=a[(n-d+j)%n];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        a[i]=p[i];
    }
    // for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    // {
    //     cout<<p[i]<<" ";
    // }
    // cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        cout<<p[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main(){
    int n,d;
    // n is array size and d is the number by which we have to rotate the array
    cin>>n>>d;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    rotate_arary_by_d(a,n,d);
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is undefined behavior in your code.

```
int *p;
```

should be modified to

```
int *p = new int[n]
```

in order to allocate the memory needed. The output now should be `4 5 6 1 2 3`.